# In kubernetes do containers inside the POD have their own IP addresses?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes do containers inside the POD have their own IP addresses?

In Kubernetes Nodes will have IP address and PODs will have IP addresses, Do containers inside the pods will also have IP address of their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they share the same networking namespace. Hence if you bind to a port on 127.0.0.1 on one container you can connect to that port on the other etc.